# What is the syntax on how to align text in center when using div and a h1 class with css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the following in Wordpress Storefront Theme

```
<div class="entry-content">
   <div id="pl-31" class="panel-layout">
      <h1 class="panel-grid panel-no-style" style="text-align: left;"> hello all</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

and I am trying to center my `h1`, which is included in **wordpress post**, but I am confused with the syntax in CSS . I cannot figure out which class actually is used.

`style="text-align: left"` is included in Element.style.

So, how to syntax my CSS properly here?

I tried this

```
.pl-31{

margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#pl-31 .panel-grid.panel-no-style{

text-align:center !important;

}
```

but hello all just moved only a bit to the right..

Comment: simply change left with center

Comment: h1.panel-grid panel-no-style{
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:auto;
 margin-right:auto;
 
} is not working if you mean this

Comment: make it  `h1.panel-grid.panel-no-style{ text-align:center!important; }`

Comment: by the way i meant to change the inline style in your code :) but i suppose you cannot

Comment: no effect with !important

Comment: check well the code i added, i modified the selector also, not only the important

Comment: shall I do somthing with container div of h1? or not?

Comment: am not sure about the other CSS but logically no as it's a block element by default and it takes full width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is just to change `left` to `center` in the inline attribute, as was mentioned in the comments.

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div id="pl-31" class="panel-layout">
    <h1 class="panel-grid panel-no-style" style="text-align: center;"> hello all</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or to remove the attribute altogether and put `text-align: center` in the stylesheet.

```css
#pl-31 > h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div id="pl-31" class="panel-layout">
    <h1 class="panel-grid panel-no-style"> hello all</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

But if, as you hint, you cannot change the HTML, only the CSS, then we'll have to resort to a little trickery.

```css
#pl-31 {
  text-align:center; /* center the whole pl-31 */
}

#pl-31 > * {
  text-align:initial; /* but not other elements inside */
}

#pl-31 > h1 {
  display:inline-block; /* make the h1 as wide as its contents */
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
   <div id="pl-31" class="panel-layout">
      <h1 class="panel-grid panel-no-style" style="text-align: left;"> hello all</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

There you go. Hope this helps!

PS In the comments you also mention that `text-align:center !important` in the stylesheet doesn't work, but it does, actually. So not sure what goes wrong there.

Comment: am pretty sure he has more CSS than he suspect applying to the elements and he's using Wordpress so the inline style is generated automatically. So we cannot help him unless he show us his full code ... it could be a float property or a fixed width somewhere.

Comment: thank you very much for your remarks and suggestion I just want to add that I added and a margin:  0 auto; with a small padding to make the div inner box centered